# Unable to add DataGridViewButtonColumn on right in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have built a WinForms application with a DataGridView. I would like to add button columns for `Edit` and `Delete` at the end (right side).

I have code like this for data binding:

```
public FrmMain()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    var editColumn = new DataGridViewButtonColumn  //Adding Edit column
    {
        Text = "Edit",
        UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true,
        Name = "Edit",
        DataPropertyName = "Edit"
    };
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(editColumn);
    var delColumn = new DataGridViewButtonColumn  //Adding Delete Column
    {
        Text = "Delete",
        UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true,
        Name = "Delete",
        DataPropertyName = "Delete"
    };
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(delColumn);
    DisplayData(); //Method to bind data in gridview
}
```

This will add the buttons at columns 0 and 1, like the attached image. How can I do this to add the buttons at the end, after the state column?

[image]

Comment: since i cant open image from my system can you please tell where exactly you want image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

N.B. I program in C#, not VB, so there may be subtle differences I am not aware of.

You are adding your button columns before you bind your data, so they are being added to an empty column collection.  As such, they become columns 0 and 1.  Then you bind your data and those new columns get added after the two button columns.

You could either try to bind your data first and then add the button columns, at which time they should appear at the end.  Or add the columns as you have them and then modify the column display order after you bind your data.

Comment: I tried everything instead of this last day.So simple I forgot the basics :( . Thanks and it works fine now :)

Answer (score 0):

You may try using [displayIndex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y4txykz8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property:

```
delColumn.displayIndex = yourIndex;
```

Or try using [Insert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/469kbaft%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) function.

**EDIT: **

Try like this:

```
public FrmMain()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    var editColumn = new DataGridViewButtonColumn  //Adding Edit column
    {
        Text = "Edit",
        UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true,
        Name = "Edit",
        DataPropertyName = "Edit"
    };
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(editColumn);
    var delColumn = new DataGridViewButtonColumn  //Adding Delete Column
    {
        Text = "Delete",
        UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true,
        Name = "Delete",
        DataPropertyName = "Delete"
    };
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(delColumn);

    // Set after adding to collection
    editColumn.DisplayIndex = 3;
    delColumn.DisplayIndex = 4;

    DisplayData(); //Method to bind data in gridview
}
```

Comment: I used like this,but did't work for me
var editColumn = new DataGridViewButtonColumn
            {
                Text = "Edit",
                DisplayIndex = 4,
                UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true,
                Name = "Edit",
                DataPropertyName = "Edit"
            };
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(editColumn);

Comment: Shows " ArgumentOutOfRangeException","The DisplayIndex property of a DataGridViewColumn must be smaller than the number of columns" and if I am changing DisplayIndex to 0 and 1 respectively it works fine.

Comment: You have to adjust the index as per your need.

Comment: Also I tried using  dataGridView1.Columns.Insert(3, editColumn);
Shows the same exception.

Comment: I have 3 columns as per image and I have tested taking index 1-7. If taking Index 0 works fine else "ArgumentOutOfRangeException"

Comment: What are the values of `dataGridView1.Columns[i].State` for each column and what is `dataGridView1.Columns.count` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84783/discussion-between-sabyasachi-mishra-and-neverhopeless).

Comment: there are only two columns prior to binding the data, so you can't set the index higher than 1, that is the meaning of the ArgumentOutOfRangeException description.

Answer (score 0):

i have created something like this for you. As i cant see the Image but can understand your problem:
**EDIT**

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("name");
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            dt.Rows.Add("");
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add("");
        }
        this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        this.dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width = 100;

        Button edit = new Button();
        edit.Text = "Edit";
        Button delete = new Button();
        delete.Text = "Delete";
        this.dataGridView1.Controls.Add(edit);
        //set its location and size to fit the cell
        edit.Location = this.dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(3, 0, true).Location;
        edit.Size = this.dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(4, 0, true).Size;

        this.dataGridView1.Controls.Add(delete);
        //set its location and size to fit the cell
        delete.Location = this.dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(2, 3, true).Location;
        delete.Size = this.dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(0, 1, true).Size;
    }
```

[image: edit delete button image]

Comment: After adding this I can't able to see the edit and delete buttons.

Comment: check editied code please sorry i mistakenly increased Width.

Comment: Buttons are showing in the footer(Not in the right hand side).

Comment: for me it is showing in the left 1and 2 box, and exactly matching your requirement please use this code once and try.

Comment: I hope you can see mine one now.

Comment: My question was, my data should show in 1st 3 columns then at 3rd and 4th column index my edit and Delete button should show.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84785/discussion-between-deshdeep-singh-and-sabyasachi-mishra).

Answer (score 0):

this is the one to add in for all of your ids.:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int j, i;
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("name");
            for ( j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            {
                dt.Rows.Add("");
            }
            for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add("");
            }
            this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            this.dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width = 100;


            for (int k = 0; k < dt.Rows.Count; k++ )
            {
                Button edit = new Button();
                edit.Text = "Edit";
                Button delete = new Button();
                delete.Text = "Delete";
                this.dataGridView1.Controls.Add(edit);
                this.dataGridView1.Controls.Add(delete);                      
                //set its location and size to fit the cell
                edit.Location = this.dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(3, k, true).Location;
                edit.Size = this.dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(0, 1, true).Size;

                //set its location and size to fit the cell
                delete.Location = this.dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(4, k, true).Location;
                delete.Size = this.dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(0, 1, true).Size;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was just faced with the same problem and stumbled upon this question. While the other answers work, I was inspired to try a simpler approach.

You can use the [DataBindingComplete](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.databindingcomplete.aspx) method to know when data has been bound and add the column then (effectively inserting it at the end). However, a small bump in the road was this:

> This event is raised when the contents of the data source change or
>   when the value of the DataSource, DataMember, or BindingContext
>   property changes.

In other words, the event is fired more than once, even just for `dataGrid.DataSource = mySource;`. To work around this, I added a check to see if the column I want to add already exists. If not, I add my button column:

```
private void myGridView_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
{
    if (!myGridView.Columns.Contains("Remove"))
    {
        DataGridViewButtonColumn removeColumn = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
        removeColumn.Name = "Remove";
        removeColumn.HeaderText = "Remove";
        removeColumn.DataPropertyName = "Remove";
        removeColumn.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
        myGridView.Columns.Add(removeColumn);
    }
}
```

In my case I just wanted to add a button for 'Remove' which would remove the row. Hopefully you see the concept and can adjust this solution to match your needs. Make sure you set the `Name` property of the button column, or `.Contains()` will return false.

---

I would like to note that this also can lead to confusing behavior regarding column index, so when you are looking for a button click in `CellClick` or `CellContentClick` you may want to check column name, instead of column index. [See this question for more details.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31970292/datagridview-cellclick-event-args-are-using-strange-column-indexes)