# DataGridView_CellClick event args are using strange column indexes

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView in my WinForms application that I populate using data binding:

```
myGridView.DataSource = myDataList;
```

Once the list has been bound, I add a DataGridViewButtonColumn at the end (right side) of the DataGridView. I handle this in the DataBindingComplete event:

```
private void myGridView_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
{
    if (!myGridView.Columns.Contains("Remove"))
    {
        DataGridViewButtonColumn removeColumn = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
        removeColumn.Name = "Remove";
        removeColumn.HeaderText = "Remove";
        removeColumn.DataPropertyName = "Remove";
        removeColumn.Text = "Remove";
        removeColumn.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
        _removeColumnIndex = myGridView.Columns.Add(removeColumn);
    }
}
```

In the end, my DataGridView has the following columns:

```
| Date | Quantity | Cumulative Quantity | Rejected | Cumulative Rejected | Remove |
```

According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bc3sctb6(v=VS.110).aspx) the `Add` method will return the index of the added column. Since indexing starts at 0, and following from left to right the index of the remove column should be 5. Using the debugger, I have verified that `_removeColumnIndex` is in fact equal to 5.

The strange behavior comes inside my `CellClick` event:

```
private void myGridView_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
   if(e.ColumnIndex == _removeColumnIndex)
   {
      // Remove row
   }
}
```

When I click my remove button, the row is not being removed. Using the debugger, I found out that when I click on the remove button `e.ColumnIndex` has a value of 0. Because it's not equal to 5, the remove doesn't happen. I have used the debugger on all other columns; The order from left to right is: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0.

Why is it that the `myGridView.Columns.Add()` method returns the proper index of 5, but the DataGridViewCellEventArgs considers that column as index 0, even though it is at the right side of the grid columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Column's index changed because you DataSource of the `DataGridView` was updated(reset) before `CellClick` event was fired

I assume other columns was generated by `DataGridView` (you have `DataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = true`

So after binding was complete and columns generate you added a `Remove` column
When `DataSource` was resetted generated columns was removed and generated again,
but your manually added column remains and get index = 0(first column)

Use column name for checking a column inside `CellClick` event handler

```
private void myGridView_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridView dgv = (DataGridView)sender;   
    if(dgv.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name.Equals("Remove") == true)
    {
       // Remove row
    }
}
```

Comment: I suspect this happened because [DataBindingComplete is fired multiple times](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1037006/3131147) but the display order didn't change. It's odd that the column indexes would suddenly reflect something other than the displayed order. Any suggestions for a fix?

Comment: You are absolutely right. Following this through with a debugger, It's called three times. I think one for setting the data source, one for inserting the rows, and one for adding the remove column. I don't want to begin making an assumption that _removeColumnIndex will be 0, so do you have a suggestion for a fix? Should I compare based on column name instead of column index?